# How to use parse.com api for local login without internet connection?

Tags: parse-platform

I have implemented the sign up and login functionality using parse.com api, but I wanted to get logged in offline? does parse.com has the functionality for offline login?

Thanks

Comment: How can you log in without a connection to the user and credentials database?

Comment: And what would you imagine being able to do if you did manage to login somehow while offline?

Comment: thank you for commenting, Actually I am working on a project that is having offline functionality because the application will used by rural area people, and once they go online all the data is synced. Do you have any suggestion?